# Calling filtering conditions in DT datatables

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

I am building a shiny app that uses `DT::renderDataTable()`. It offers an elegant panel for visualizing and filtering the dataset.

I know that `DT::renderDataTable` automatically passes the filtered dataset to further operations. But for some reason now I need to also **dynamically call those filtering conditions**. By "call the filtering conditions" I mean extracting the exact expression of this condition. For instance if I changed the filtering of variable `x` to be within range `(-1, 1)`, I want to output an expression of `(x > -1) & (x < 1)` or something like this.

Anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the search strings with `input$<tableId>_search_columns`.
They use a custom format (e.g. a range of (-1, 1) would be `"-1 ... 1"`),
and there’s no exposed API in DT for parsing R expressions from the search
strings, so you’d need write a parser yourself.

Here’s a function that should get you started:

```r
parse_search_expressions <- function(data, search) {
  parse_search_expression <- function(x, s) {
    if (!nzchar(s)) return(TRUE)
    if (is.numeric(x)) {
      r <- strsplit(s, "...", fixed = TRUE)
      r <- sapply(r, as.numeric)
      bquote((x >= .(r[1])) & (x <= .(r[2])))
    } else if (is.factor(x) || is.logical(x)) {
      v <- jsonlite::fromJSON(s)
      bquote(x %in% .(v))
    } else {
      bquote(grepl(.(s), x, fixed = TRUE))
    }
  }
  Map(parse_search_expression, data, search)
}

tbl <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = factor(LETTERS[1:3]), z = c("foo", "bar", "baz"))
str(parse_search_expressions(tbl, c("1 ... 2", "[\"A\"]", "ba")))
#> List of 3
#>  $ x: language (x >= 1) & (x <= 2)
#>  $ y: language x %in% "A"
#>  $ z: language grepl("ba", x, fixed = TRUE)
```

If you just want to apply the filter, there’s `doColumnSearch()` (added in
DT 0.22) which will let you get the indices matching a search string:

```r
str(Map(DT::doColumnSearch, tbl, c("1 ... 2", "[\"A\"]", "ba")))
#> List of 3
#>  $ x: int [1:2] 1 2
#>  $ y: int 1
#>  $ z: int [1:2] 2 3
```

I’d recommend the latter if that’s sufficient, since you’re guaranteed to
get the same result as the DT filtering. With the first approach you have
to duplicate the filtering logic, and it’s on you to make sure the result
is the same.

Finally, here’s how to use both approaches in an app:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table"),
  verbatimTextOutput("expression"),
  verbatimTextOutput("search_result")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderDT(iris, filter = "top")
  output$expression <- renderPrint({
    str(parse_search_expressions(iris, input$table_search_columns))
  })
  output$search_result <- renderPrint({
    str(Map(doColumnSearch, iris, input$table_search_columns))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```